# how to check if databases values are already exists

Tags: python, mysql, discord, discord.py

i'm creating a discord bot that count the amount of messages that the user sending, and i'm in the beginning, i want to check if the user id and guild id is already inserted or not, because when i run the and send messages it just duplicating the same guild id and the user id.
How can i solve that ?

this is my code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    sql = ("INSERT INTO citizens (guild_id, user_id) VALUES (%s, %s)")
    val = (message.guild.id, message.author.id)
    mycursor.execute(sql, val)

    mydb.commit()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have an unique constraint on `guild_id, user_id` and add try catch on `mycursor.execute(sql, val)` .

Answer (score 0):

You could start with a query checking in your database if the values already exist and then perform an update of the existing values.